# Best way to "float" a clone of a view into the center of the screen like a dialog?

Tags: android

Take any view on the UI. It could also be any level of nesting into a page's layout. After double-tapping the view, have that view (or copy) float and popup into the center of the screen like a dialog.

It doesn't need to be a dialog though. The requirement however is that all threads in the current activity (UI and background) cannot be interrupted (not a dialog, not another activity).

**My current plan** is to dynamically add a floating XML layout like RelativeLayout into the supermost layout of the current page (with/without an overlay on the entire page to block views from being touched). This floating clone will have highest elevation; drop shadows aren't important. The target view is a 3rd-party plugin view called LineChart from MPAndroidChart. I want to copy all of its data into this clone, detach/redirect the original from its accessors and hide it because it's being accessed and fed data (possibly delete it if the clone has data integrity for a copyback).

This is definitely an option, but I wanted to know if there a native (...maybe a plugin) class that has support for popping out any view (while unaffecting current context and not stopping the UI or other threads).

Comment: Can you explain a bit more and concise!

Comment: your plan is good stick with it.

Comment: @ZafarKurbonov In the activity I'm working with, I have: the UI, a handler with a weak reference to the UI, 4 background threads (being queued by my concurrency controller), a client for either USB or Bluetooth connections (if Bluetooth there is also my service running to control its connection), all of this connected to proprietary instruments that are feeding data into the page.\nBecause of the nature of these connections, I should NOT close them else I have to reestablish connections or I have to cache the connection state. So, if I make any changes, it should remain in the current context.

Comment: @ZafarKurbonov meanwhile with all of this noise, I have a view (LineChart) that I want to double/long press that will float it (or its copy) into the center of the page.